# Rand() still generate 0 even I set the minimun as 1 in C programming

Tags: c

```
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <time.h>
# include <string.h>
void sort(int a[], int m){
// define a sort function to help sort the numbers in array from min to max
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int tmp = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m - 1; i++){
        for (j = 0; j < m -i - 1; j++){
            if (a[j] > a[j+1]){
            tmp = a [j+1];
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            a[j] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(){

    int capacity = 18;
    int stopTime = 15;
    int floors = 20;
    int movePerFloorTime = 3;
    double averageTotalTime = 0;
    double minTotalTime = 0;
    double maxTotalTime = 0;
    double averageTimePerPassenger = 0;

    srand(1);
    int passengers = rand() % (capacity + 1);
    int i = 0;
    printf("%d\n",passengers);
    int *destination;
    destination = (int*)malloc( passengers*sizeof(int)); // create an array with a random length of number of passengers
    for (i = 0; i < passengers; i++){
        destination[i] = rand() % floors + 1;
        sort(destination, passengers);
        printf("%d ", destination[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I've set the minimum value of rand() as 1 but it still generates number 0. Use a sort function to sort the array by size so that it's more clear.Can somebody help me figure it out? Thanks.
The output is like this:

10

0 0 0 0 0 8 9 15 15 18

Comment: Did you mean to use `int passengers = 1 + (rand() % capacity);`?

Comment: You set the minimum to 1 when setting `destination[i]`, but not when setting `passengers`.

Comment: BTW `20 + 1 - 1` is just `20`.

Comment: passengers could be zero so I didn't set it. All I need is to make destination[i] to generate values from 1 to 20.

Comment: I suggest you write a function `randrange(int lo, int hi)` that returns numbers in the range `lo..hi`, and then use that consistently when setting `passengers`, `destination[i]`, etc.

Comment: What is `sort(destination, passengers);` supposed to do?

Comment: That is a function I write before to sort the array by size.

Comment: @Barmar: For integers a and b, the number of integers in an interval [a, b], that is one that includes both its endpoints, is b+1-a, hence the number for [20, 1] is 20+1-1. It makes sense to express it this way if the number is used similarly elsewhere, as it illustrates the derivation of the expression to the reader and alerts them to be thoughtful about off-by-one errors.

Comment: @EricPostpischil OK. I guess `20` should be `floors`.

Comment: @levi.weiwei So why didn't you include the code for the `sort` function in your post? It could be pretty important if it's going to modify `destination`, don't you think?

Comment: It may be that calling your `sort` routine is premature. Since it is passed `passengers` and not `i`, it may be sorting the entire array before it is filled in. That means it will be sorting uninitialized data, which can easily inject zeros. Edit the question to provide a [mre]. Included in that, for debugging purposes, replace `srand((unsigned) (time(NULL)));` with `srand(1);` or some other seed that reproduces the problem. That way, you will have the same data from run to run while debugging. Either reproduce the problem without the `sort` call or put the `sort` routine in the posted code.

Comment: When you are done, the posted code should compile with **no** errors or warnings and produce a complete program that others can reproduce to run the program. (One difficulty there is `rand` is not fully specified, so not everybody will get the same results. There are ways around that, by replacing `srand` and `rand` by hard-coded alternatives, but let’s skip that for the moment.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I've posted the whole code. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the loop, `sort(destination, passengers);` sorts the entire array pointed to by `destination` even though the array is not entirely filled in.

Move `sort(destination, passengers);` after the loop.

Comment: I got it. Now it works. Thanks.